# Custom styled Google Map controls

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am working in a project with this requirement and found no success.

What I need is this:[image]

For custom markers I followed this site.[Link](http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php)

Is it possible to have these type of custom styled controls in Google Map Api, if yes then how can I achieve it. I searched internet with terms like **Custom styled  controls Google Map** and many more but found no success.

Please shed some light on it.
Thanks in advance, Ankur

Comment: Did you consider viewing the source of that page? :-)

Comment: Bro Google blocks right click on the page.

Comment: Google maps are fully developed using Ajax, Ajax developed controls are not shown in that source..:)

Comment: Those controls are custom controls. They are not Google's own.

Comment: that is the psd I shown in the image, that's not the running website. I have to create like that.

Comment: This should give a solution for your problem. Couldn't post it as an answer because it's closed. Don't know if you can change everything but it should help: and yes it is api v3 :)  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomDrawing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Developers docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls?hl=nl-NL#Custom_Controls). It shows you how to create custom controls.

Comment: that api is going to be deprecated in May 19, 2013.
:(

Comment: I just find out on an other SO question that custom controls are not possible in v3. Here is a link to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916555/custom-google-map-api-v3-zoom-buttons

Comment: Sorry man :) You have to deal with the style of google maps.

Comment: @ankur20us: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction