# Google Map V3 Zoom Buttons with CSS and Image

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

How do I replace google map V3 zoom buttons with my own image?  I have tried the below css from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916555/custom-google-map-api-v3-zoom-buttons) but it is not showing up.  What do I need to do to make it show up on the map?  I don't mind the first solution on the post either but I need it to be an image and sit inside the map not separate.

```
#map-container .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint { background: url(/images/map-zoom- controls.png) no-repeat center center !important; width: 42px !important; height: 68px !important; }
#map-container .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint > div > img { display: none !important; }
#map-container .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom in"] { top: 2px   !important; left: 2px !important; width: 38px !important; height: 31px !important; }
#map-container .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom out"] { top: 35px !important; left: 2px !important; width: 38px !important; height: 30px !important; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps custom control always appears below the default controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266309/google-maps-custom-control-always-appears-below-the-default-controls/21272069#21272069) (cotains an example of a custom zoom control)

Answer (score -1):

I Got This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
#map-canvas .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint { background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picons-basic-1/57/basic1-171_add_new_plus-128.png) no-repeat center center !important; width: 42px !important; height: 68px !important; }
#map-canvas .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint > div > img { display: none !important; }
#map-canvas .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom in"] { top: 2px !important; left: 2px !important; width: 38px !important; height: 31px !important; }
#map-canvas .gm-style > .gmnoprint > .gmnoprint div[title="Zoom out"] { top: 35px !important; left: 2px !important; width: 38px !important; height: 30px !important; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added big plus button that changes the zoom

Comment: cracker: This doesn't work on iPad.  It shows the default buttons on top of the plus image.  Is there a way to get rid of the default in iPad?  I tried **zoomControl: false,** but it got rid of the plus image too.

Comment: scrollwheel: false
scaleControl: false, you need to add this in mapoptions.