# Custom Google Map API V3 PEGMAN Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made custom zoom controls and want to add Pegman control with the same style as well. Is it possible?

Custom zoom controls are added as follows (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916555/custom-google-map-api-v3-zoom-buttons) questions answer):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 60%; width:60%; margin:20px auto; border:1px solid; padding-left:100px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-MAP_API-ID&sensor=false&region=AU">
    </script>



<script type="text/javascript">

function HomeControl(controlDiv, map) {

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomout, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 0){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel - 1);}     
  });

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomin, 'click', function() {
   var currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
   if(currentZoomLevel != 21){
     map.setZoom(currentZoomLevel + 1);}
  });

}

var map;
var markersArray = [];


function initialize() {

  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.90224, 151.20215);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng,
    Marker: true,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false,
     mapTypeControl: false,
     mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title:"Hello World!"
  });

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and
  // call the HomeControl() constructor passing
  // in this DIV.
  var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);    

</script>

</head>




  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="zoomout" style="border:1px solid; width:150px; heoght:50px; cursor:pointer; margin-bottom:20px;">ZOOM ME OUT</div>
    <div id="zoomin" style="border:1px solid; width:150px; heoght:50px;cursor:pointer;">ZOOM ME IN</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to add one more `div` element in the body with custom Pegman button, but it need to work exactly as it is working in default button (drag and drop yellow man to the map, Pegman is moving on hover etc) only the square button behind him will be another style.

Answer (score -1):

When you only want to style the button, not the pegman, it's quite  easy.

The button has the class `gm-svpc` , simply add your style.

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    streetViewControl: true
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.gm-svpc {
  background: tomato !important;
  border: 2px solid firebrick;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```